# Handling double for loops with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In order to handle modificiations on multiple DataFrames, I have a piece of code that works, but I'd like to improve it's efficiency.

I'm sure that there is a better solution to this problem.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [2]: df

Out[2]: 
       A  B
    0  1  2
    1  1  3
    2  4  6

In [1]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]], columns=['C', 'D'])

In [2]: df2

Out[2]: 
       C  D
    0  1  1
    1  1  1
    2  1  1
```

In fact to identify values and replace in function of an equality for example, I use double for llop to browse Dataframes :

```
for i in range(0, df['A'].size):
    for j in range(0, df2['C'].size):
        if df.loc[i,'A'] == df2.loc[j, 'C'] :
            df2.loc[j, 'C'] = df.loc[i,'B']
        else :
            pass
In [2]: df2

Out[2]: 
       C  D
    0  2  1
    1  3  1
    2  1  1
```

This action is really simple but is not suitable for processing large DataFrames,
Thanks a lot in advance

**EDIT** : The Dataframes aren't necessarily the same size

Comment: how would you like to handle the data that exceeds minimal size ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are handling dataframe of same size, in that case

```
df2.loc[df2['C'] == df['A'], 'C'] = df['B']
```

You get

```
    C   D
0   2   1
1   3   1
2   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks ! my bad i didn't mentionned that the dataframes aren't necessarily the same size :)

Comment: So you would be comparing the values till the dataframe sizes match and then ignore the rest of the rows?

Comment: I just want to compare two columns which have not the same size, get the matching index and modify a field corresponding to this index